# How to get a proper table design( 0NF) for my database

Tags: database, conceptual

I have to design tables in 0NF for my project, I am required to design the tables in 0NF form first then proceed to normalization and then draw the ERD. However it has been a real challenge for me to obtain the 0NF forms of my tables, lots of time has been wasted trying to redesign so I thought of asking help from people who might be more experienced in database design.

My database is of a Car Rental System. The system should keep records of customers,cars,employees, details of each rental and also the company is supposed to have multiple branches at different locations and each branch must have their own set of unique(identified by their license plate number) cars available.

1. One customer can have multiple rental records(i.e. made a rental in January then another in March .e.t.c) but one rental record is related to only one customer
2. A customer can book multiple cars in a single rental
3. Each rental is made through a single booking agent(an employee)
4. Employees is divided between Managers and booking agents. Each branch has a single manager but multiple booking agents.
5. Each branch has multiple cars located there but each car can be located at a single branch

So far, I've come up with these 0NF tables, they don't look correct to me though:

**Cars**(CarID,LicensePlateNo,Make,Model,Year,Color,mileage,Capacity,seats,Availability, Rate, BranchID,BranchLocation)

**Customer**(CustomerID, FirstName,LastName, Address ,ContactNo,Gender,DOB,NIC,RentalID,DateRented,RentalCost)

**Agent**(AgentID,FirstName,LastName,Address,ContactNo,Gender,DOB,NIC,MonthlyRentals,Salary,ManagerID,ManagerName,MangerLastName,ManagerAddress,ManagerContact,BranchID,BranchLocation)

**Rental**(RentalID,DateRented,Duration,RentalCost,Discount,AgentID,CarID,LicensePlateNo,Make,Model)

**Branch**(BranchID,BranchName,BranchLocation,ContactNumber,ManagerID)

Answer (score -1):

I have replaced the **Agent** table with the **Employee** table and I have added 2 new columns (**Position** and **Manager**) to it. I believe the **position** column should store either 'Agent' or 'Manager'. If employee is an Agent, the Manager field should contain the ID of his/her Manager (**EmployeeID**). If employee is  Manager, most probably the **Manager** column should be left NULL. I have also removed all other columns which were being repeated(Example **BranchLocation** in **cars** table etc...)

Cars(CarID,LicensePlateNo,Make,Model,Year,Color,Mileage,Capacity,Seats,Availability, Rate, BranchID)

Customer(CustomerID, FirstName,LastName,Address,ContactNo,Gender,DOB,NIC,RentalID)

Rental(RentalID,DateRented,Duration,RentalCost,Discount,EmployeeID,CarID)

Branch(BranchID,BranchName,BranchLocation,ContactNumber,EmployeeID)

Employee(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Address,ContactNo,Gender,DOB,NIC,MonthlyRentals,Salary,BranchID,Position,Manager)

Thanks